# d3: position text element dependent on length of element before

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm stuck in d3 (or JavaScript in general).

I want to make a legend with d3. The position of the 9 items should be dependent on each other. More specifically:

This is my simplified array:
var dataset = ["Africa","Asia", "Caribbean", "Central America", "Europe", "Middle East", "North America", "Oceania", "South America"];

On the x-axis, I want to draw the next text 40px futher (to the right) then the last text lable ended. My intention is to have the same space between the circles every time. So the next text is always dependent on the length of the last country name.

I tried this:

```
.attr("x", function(d, i) {return i * 40 + d[i-1].length + 7;})
```

but the console says d[i-1] is undefined.

What am I missing? How would you solve this?

Many thanks in advance! Your help is very much appreciated!

Ewa

UPDATE:
Actually the legend I want to draw not only consists of the text, but also little circles.

Here is the array (with hard coded x_pos as d[2]: var dataset = [
           ["Africa", "#4B7985", 5], ["Asia", "#58AB86", 55], ["Caribbean", "#63A4B5", 100], ["Central America", "#818181", 165], ["Europe", "#E9726C", 255], ["Middle East", "#E3AC73", 310], ["North America", "#B65856", 383], ["Oceania", "#287E5C", 470], ["South America", "#AC8358", 530]
            ];

How do I draw the circles dependent on the length of the country names and get the same spacing between the cirlces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can draw text element to get bounding box on canvas. Then adjust position based on the last element's width:

```
svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(data).enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x_pos;
  })
  .attr("y", 50)
  .style("display", "none")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });

svg.selectAll("text")
  .style("display", "block")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    var c_pos = x_pos;
    x_pos = x_pos + this.getBBox().width + distance;
    return c_pos;
  });
```

Full example: https://vida.io/documents/C5CSjbWLhoJ8rQmhF

Comment: Thanks a lot Phuoc! This works perfectly! :) But, I only told part of the story and stumbled upon a problem again. Actually the legend I want to draw not only consists of the text, but also little circles. Here is the array (with hard coded x_pos as d[2]: var dataset = [
        ["Africa", "#4B7985", 5], ["Asia", "#58AB86", 55], ["Caribbean", "#63A4B5", 100], ["Central America", "#818181", 165], ["Europe", "#E9726C", 255], ["Middle East", "#E3AC73", 310], ["North America", "#B65856", 383], ["Oceania", "#287E5C", 470], ["South America", "#AC8358", 530]
   ];

Comment: So, what now? I can't use "this." anymore to draw the circles dependent on the length of the country name, right? So, this is why I came up with d[i-1] (or rahter dataset[0][i-1] in that case??).

Comment: You can shift the text a little bit to have space for legend. Something like: x_pos = x_pos + this.getBBox().width + distance + legend_space. And legend pos is: x_pos = x_pos + this.getBBox().width + distance;

Comment: Thanks for your reply Phuoc Do! I tried this and apprently I get the width of the circles' boxes as "this" refers to the circles now. How can I tell d3 to use the text width?

Comment: I see. It's a bit tricky to do. I updated my example with circle in front of text.

Comment: Awesome! You're awesome! :) So the magic trick is "this.parentNode.childNodes[0]". Need to dive into this in depth. Am not familiar with it so far. Thanks a lot for your patient help! :)

Comment: Yes, that helps you figure out the width of text element to position your legend.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.

```
//This will be your array of legends
var legendItems = [] 

var legendCount = legendItems.length;
var legendSectionWidth = width / (legendCount+1);
//This will be your "y" value going forward. You can assign anything you want. I have used the following if else case, you should replace it with your logic to calculate y.
var vert = 0;
if(legendPosition == "bottom"){
    if(showAxes)
        vert = height + legendVerticalPad + containerHeight*0.04;
    else
        vert = height + legendVerticalPad + containerHeight*0.02;
}

for(var i = 0; i < legendCount; i++){
    var text = svg.append('text')
        .attr('x', (i+1)*legendSectionWidth)
        .attr('y', vert)
        .attr('class', 'legend-text '+legendItems[i])
        .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .style('dominant-baseline', 'central')
        .text(function() {
            return legendItems[i];
        });

    var len = text[0][0].getComputedTextLength();

// you could use circles here, just change the width n height to rx and x and y to cx and cy// you could use circles here, just change the width n height to rx and x and y to cx and cy`enter code here`
//The value 5 is your choice, i use 5px between my rect and text
    svg.append('rect') 
        .attr('x', (i+1)*legendSectionWidth - len/2 - 5 - legendRectSize)
        .attr('y', vert - legendRectSize/2)
        .attr('width', legendRectSize)
        .attr('height', legendRectSize)
        .attr('class', function () { return 'legend '+ legendItems[i];} )
        .attr('label', function()  {
            return legendItems[i]; 
        })
}
```

The result is something like this
[image: Sample legends]

The following images prove that the legends(combo of rect and text) are equi-distant from each and place right in the center of the provided width. And with this logic, no matter what is the no of legends you need, all will be placed equi-distant from each other and show up right in the middle of the screen

[image: 5 legends]

[image: 4 legends]

[image: 3 legends]

[image: 2 legends]

[image: 1 legend]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First off, `d` refers to an individual, bound data point, while `i` refers to its index in the dataset. To look at the previous data point, you would need to reference the original dataset, rather than the provided datapoint.

Assuming you had:

```
var dataset = ["Africa","Asia", "Caribbean", "Central America", "Europe", "Middle East", "North America", "Oceania", "South America"];

d3.select('.foo').data(dataset)....
```

You would want to change your d[i - 1] references in your position handler to dataset[i - 1]

With that fixed, your first element will still blow up, since it's at `dataset[0]`. `dataset[i - 1]` is `dataset[-1]` in that case.

You could change your return statement to:

```
return i ? (i * 40 + dataset[i-1].length + 7) : i;
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that this is most probably  a problem. But I tried to eliminate this with an if statement, but it did not help. O gosh, I am sorry, but I am a pretty newby to JS. Are ? and : Coffescript or can I copy/paste it like you've written it?

Comment: No worries. That's just a ternary statement. Standard javascript you can cut and paste. Basically it says if i is truthy (1 or more) then do the math. Otherwise return i. Check out this link for more info :) http://javascript.about.com/od/byexample/a/ternary-example.htm

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification. And for your suggestion! Unfortunately it isn't working either. I tried: if (i == 0) {
      return 5;
      }
      else if (i > 0) {
      return i * 60 + d[i - 1].length + 7;
      } in the anonymous function. But I still get a "d[i - 1] is undefined". What might be wrong with d[i - 1]?

Comment: D'oh, this is really stupid. I was focused entirely on the indexing error, but I didn't notice your original array (1-dimensional). D just refers to the element in your array. You would want to use dataset to refer to the overall dataset you supplied to d3.

Comment: Gopherkhan, thanks! With "dataset" instead of "d" it works! But the result is not as desired. I seem to have an error in the math...