# Calculate width of text before drawing the text

Tags: d3.js

I want to display a `rect` with a `text` label next to it. The width of the `rect` should stretch to the width of the svg container, less the width of the the text, which is dynamic and can be of any variable length.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwarvnj2/)

```
var text = 'Foobar';
var textWidth = 50; //how to calculate this?
var plotWidth = 400;
var barWidth = plotWidth-textWidth;

var plot = d3.select(container)
        .insert("svg")
        .attr('width', plotWidth)
        .attr('height', 50);

plot.append("rect")
    .style("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("width", barWidth)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("height", 50);

plot.append("text")
    .attr("x", barWidth)
    .attr("y", 28)
    .text(text);
```

How do I calculate the width of the text using D3, before it is drawn? Or how do I otherwise position and size elements that depend on the dimensions of variable length text?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224611/d3-position-text-element-dependent-on-length-of-element-before

Comment: One simple solution I use in situation where a function to measure the text is not easy to come by is to utilize the font-size in pixels. Width = number of chars * size in pixels. Height = size in pixels. Some minor adjustment may be necessary with height.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21486622

Answer (score 31):

I know you asked about D3, but this might be a native solution to your issue.

The HTML5 canvas 2D context has some built-in functionality to measure text. You might be able to tap into that to measure text for other APIs like SVG. If it's not 100% accurate, surely it's proportional to the correct answer.

```
var BrowserText = (function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    /**
     * Measures the rendered width of arbitrary text given the font size and font face
     * @param {string} text The text to measure
     * @param {number} fontSize The font size in pixels
     * @param {string} fontFace The font face ("Arial", "Helvetica", etc.)
     * @returns {number} The width of the text
     **/
    function getWidth(text, fontSize, fontFace) {
        context.font = fontSize + 'px ' + fontFace;
        return context.measureText(text).width;
    }

    return {
        getWidth: getWidth
    };
})();

// Then call it like this:
console.log(BrowserText.getWidth('hello world', 22, 'Arial')); // 105.166015625
console.log(BrowserText.getWidth('hello world', 22)); // 100.8154296875
```

Comment: We found this to be a great approach to avoiding the issue of getComputedTextLength triggering a render for every call.  Obviously if you're going to make a large number of calls, it's worth creating the canvas and canvascontext once, then just calling measureText for each string.

Answer (score 23):

I had a similar problem in a complex chart with lots of interactions between elements and text, which required knowing the text width **before** displaying any element.

I resorted to creating a dummy text to grab its width and immediately removing it. Note the last line of code of the function in `each`.

```
var textData = ['a', 'b', 'c']    // your text here

var textWidth = []

svg.append('g')
    .selectAll('.dummyText')     // declare a new CSS class 'dummyText'
    .data(textData)
    .enter()                     // create new element
    .append("text")              // add element to class
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "14px")
    //.attr("opacity", 0.0)      // not really necessary
    .text(function(d) { return d})
    .each(function(d,i) {
        var thisWidth = this.getComputedTextLength()
        textWidth.push(thisWidth)
        this.remove() // remove them just after displaying them
    })

console.log(textWidth) // this array contains the on-screen width of each text element
```

Comment: Where does that ".dummyText" come from? Do I have to create it somewhere upfront? Will it remain there for future calculations?

Comment: It's a class name for the text you are using to gauge the width, and it will go away by itself thanks to `this.remove()`

Comment: Yeah but it never appears anywhere. The code works with it, I have no idea why, it could possibly be anything. But it fails without that line, so I left it in.

Comment: Correct, it should not appear anywhere. When you do `selectAll` you are declaring a new class `dummyText` and then with `enter` and `append` you are creating new text elements belonging to that class. Since you then `remove` each of them, you will never see them appear.

Comment: Ah, so `selectAll` can also create elements, or put another way, the selected class (even though it doesn't exist at selection time) is implicitly applied to later created elements? I couldn't see that in the documentation.

Comment: Precisely, the selected class is applied to the elements that you create with `enter()` and `text()` - admittedly it takes a moment to digest once you start with D3 (at least, that was my case)

Answer (score 11):

Here's a working example based on using <s>`getBBox().width`</s> `getComputedTextLength()`:

**Edit**: Updating the answer to use `getComputedTextLength` due to performance concerns (see comment)

http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/jzkj29nv/27/

```
var text_element = plot.select("text");
var textWidth = text_element.node().getComputedTextLength()
```

I've also switched to using `text-anchor: end;` CSS for the text, so you don't need to calculate the start position of the text (just pass in the end)

Comment: It's worth noting that getBBox() forces a render pass in the browser and so if done repeatedly can cause terrible performance issues.

Comment: Thanks - Good call! I've updated the answer to remove getBBox() and recommend getComputedTextLength

Comment: in your example its not the calculation which putting text in the end, but it is the anchor which is showing text in the end of rectangle

Comment: From my observations, getComputedTextLength also triggers rendering.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use [`getComputedTextLength()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTextContentElement#instance_methods) or [`getBBox()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) inside a d3 [`selection.attr`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v3.0.0/README.md#selection_attr).

Here's a minimal example that calculates `x` and `y` coordinates based on the size of the `text` content:

```js
d3.select('svg').append('text')
  .text('some text')
    .attr('x', function() {return this.getComputedTextLength();})
    .attr('y', (d, i, nodes) => nodes[i].getBBox().height);
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

svg text {
  fill: black;
  text-anchor: start;
  dominant-baseline: hanging;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="100"></svg>
```

Note that two function styles are used, to illustrate the following:

In a normal `function ()`, you can use either `nodes[i]` or `this` to access the [current node](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v3.0.0/README.md#selection_attr).

However, in [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `=>`, we must use `nodes[i]`, because using `this` raises an error:

```
this.getComputedTextLength is not a function
```

Also see [d3-selection issue 97](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/97#issuecomment-248397110) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45262284).